# Hibernate criteria search by age range from day of birth

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a class User which has a date of birth variable and I am trying to write a criteria query to find all users that are more than X years old and less than Y, where X and Y are two Integers and date of birth is a Date.

I solved it using this expression, but I would like to avoid the use of Expression since I guess it will only work with MySQL.

```
.createCriteria(User.class)
.add(Expression
         .sql("DATE_FORMAT( FROM_DAYS( TO_DAYS( NOW( ) ) - TO_DAYS( BIRTHDATE ) ) ,  '%Y' ) >= " + lowAge))
.add(Expression
         .sql("DATE_FORMAT( FROM_DAYS( TO_DAYS( NOW( ) ) - TO_DAYS( BIRTHDATE ) ) ,  '%Y' ) <= " + highAge))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It was an old question.
However today I resolved in this way, may be helpful for someone more:

```
Criteria=cri=session.createCriteria(YourClass.class);
Conjunction conj=Restrictions.conjunction();
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR,(-1*age));
Date birthEnd=cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR,-1);
Date birthStart=cal.getTime();
conj.add(Restrictions.gt("birthdayAttributeName", birthStart));
conj.add(Restrictions.le("birthdayAttributeName", birthEnd));
disj.add(conj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `Restrictions` instead?

```
.createCriteria(User.class)
.add(Restrictions.ge("birthdate", lowAge))
.add(Restrictions.le("birthdate", highAge))
```

`birthdate` being the date of birth field for your `User` class.

Comment: I edited my first post. I can't because lowAge is an Integer and birthdate is a Date.

Comment: Can't you convert ages to birthdate? Should be as simple as `Calendar.getInstance().add(Calendar.YEAR,-1 * lowAge).getTime()` or something. Or are there locale issues with not doing the calculation within the database?